# Need help in java search

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, binary

Ok so I have to make a java program to search through an array using a binary search to find 45.3 but I am getting numerous class, interface, or enum expected errors starting after public static void main(String[] args) on line 23 can you guys help. thanks.

```
public class BinSearch
{

public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

public static int binarySearch(double[] arr, double x)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = arr.length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;

                if (arr[mid] > x)
        {
                  high = mid - 1;

                }
        else if (arr[mid] < x)
        {

          low = mid + 1;
                }
        else
        {
                   return mid+1;
                }
        }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
int j,x;
    double y,temp;
double[] arg= {-3.0, 10.0, 5.0, 24.0, 45.3, 10.5};

int i=0;
    for (j = 1; j<arg.length;j++)
{
if(arg[i]>arg[j])
{
    temp = arg[i];
    arg[i] = arg[j];
    arg[j] = temp;
}
i++;
System.out.print(arg[j-1]+",");
}


x = binarySearch(arg, 45.3);
System.out.print("45.3 found at ");
System.out.print(x);
 }
}
```

Comment: Download and use a proper IDE, [here's one option](https://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: You need to define `main` method inside a class. It can't just be roaming around in a file.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem - but please don't get into the habit of using unclear variable names.  `intArray` for an array of doubles is just confusing.  `a, x, y, i, j, t` are just about as bad.  Please try to develop a habit of choosing a name for each variable that reflects the role it plays in your program.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out, is the fact that the `main` method is declared outside of the class boundaries. The next is your `for-loop` `for (j = 1; j intArray[i + 1])` is defined incorrectly...it should follow the `for (initial; exit-condition; modifer)` pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you tried to use `public class BinSearch` as your main class. However, your parentheses enclose code before your main args.

```
     public class MyClass {

    //}// no bracket here
            public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

If you want to use a class to create Objects that use methods such as your `public static final int` , create a new class before.

```
class NewClass {

}

public class MyClass {


            public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```